Run windows 10 software on older windows versions
I have an old laptop from 2013. With 6gb ddr3 ram. Installed windows 10 but unfortunately due to lack of memory many apps/games crash or don't even launch. I reverted back to windows 8.1.
My question as suggested in the title, is there a work around to run software that is designed for windows 10 on a windows 8 PC?

No, There isn’t software must be compiled to support older versions of Windows like Windows 8

And 6GB RAM is plenty for Windows 10. The problem, if any, is NOT the amount of RAM.

Yeah that's true. Windows 10 runs okay. But when I start an app that requires lots of resources, I get error messages related primarily to RAM. Thanks for the reply

It would be possible with some virtualization, but the answer is no since you have lower hardware capacities. I guess you may have the same problem if you installed a minimal OS like Lubuntu.

@Ramhound well I almost knew the answer, but maybe someone came up with some kind of executable compiler or anything of the sorts.. anyways thanks for the reply

@oussHYK - You just have to use a compiler that still supports that version of Windows. That’s only something the author of the software can do and many times, supporting unsupported versions of Windows, means dropping features that newer versions of Windows does support

Funny thing you can run old software on modern machine/OS but the opposite is impossible for the consumer/unpractical or waste of time and money for the developers because of windows restrictions. That's a shame.
